# can not connect to the Internet via ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I want to ssh to a server and run a docker command in it. I can run docker command locally on my pc but when I connect to the server it shows this error:
`Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 408 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n". See 'docker run --help'.`
What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

I thought maybe it is a proxy issue but I disabled them all and got the error again.

Comment: First, get the image form docker-hub  with the following command: `docker pull hello-world:latest `  If there is a problem for reasons such as filtering, use the `shecan.ir` service. For this, you just need to edit the /etc/resolve.conf file.